# take profit in a specified percentage - pinescript v5 - tradingview strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to write a pinescript strategy on tradingview. I have a problem setting a limit exit profit target in percentage.

**Hypothesis**

Create a long in a determined condition, and set an exit with a limit order with take profit at 3%.

```
entry_id = str.tostring(bar_index)

long_profit_percent = input.float(3, title="Long Take Profit (%)", minval=0.0, step=1)/100 

profit_target       = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_profit_percent) 

strategy.entry(entry_id, strategy.long, comment = "long:"+entry_id) 
strategy.exit(entry_id, entry_id, limit=profit_target,comment_profit="sell:"+entry_id)
```

**Result**

In the strategy tester I see the long not closing at 3% of profit, here is an example:

[image]

Here the long and exit, in the trades table

[image]

Entry price: 47.66

Close price: 47:66

What am I not seeing? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. All the entries have the same behavior; the open and close price are the same.

I'm trying to set a long position and set (for every long) a take profit exit by 3% of profit.

My code:

```
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// 

//@version=5
strategy("test", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true,initial_capital = 1000,default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity,default_qty_value = 25,close_entries_rule = "ANY",pyramiding = 4,commission_type = format.percent, commission_value = 0.08, calc_on_every_tick = true)

fast_sma = ta.sma(close, 14)
slow_sma = ta.sma(close, 28)

long_condition = ta.crossover(fast_sma, slow_sma)

plot(fast_sma,color=color.blue)
plot(slow_sma,color=color.red)

entry_id            = str.tostring(bar_index)
long_profit_percent = input.float(3, title="Long Take Profit (%)", minval=0.0, step=1)/100
profit_target       = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_profit_percent)

if (long_condition)
    strategy.entry(entry_id, strategy.long, comment = "long:"+entry_id)
    strategy.exit(entry_id, entry_id, limit=profit_target,comment_profit="sell:"+entry_id)
```

These are my table entries

[image: table entries]

These the candelstick signals:

[image: Candestick signals]

It is as if all the trades are opening and closing in the same moment, at the same price, as I mentioned in the above images.

Comment: Thank you for adding an MRE. Note that Stack Snippets *only* support HTML, CSS and JacaScript. For any other language, it just makes things difficult to read due to the additional dialogue. Just use a regular code block, either by indenting with four spaces or encapsulating your code in code fences/triple back ticks, for other languages. See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `close_entries_rule = "ANY"` in your `strategy()`. That means, you need to specify an exit for each trade individually.

You are calculating your TP with `strategy.position_avg_price`. And then using that variable in `strategy.exit()` under the same condition that triggers the entry.

However, `strategy.position_avg_price` will be `na` until you are officially in a trade.

The problem is, for the very first entry, there is no `exit()` associated with it.

When `long_condition` is `true` for the very first trade, you call `strategy.entry()` to enter the trade and right after that you call `strategy.exit()` with `profit_target` as your TP. At this point, `profit_target` is `na` because `strategy.position_avg_price` is `na` because you are not yet in a trade.

Due to this reason, the very first trade stays open throughout the bactest period. This price is very likely to be very low compared to current price. Therefore, it effects the average price for the next orders. `strategy.position_avg_price` will still have the price from the very first entry which is probably quite low and causes your TP to be very low which also triggers your TP almost immediately.

You have `pyramiding` and `close_entries_rule = "ANY"` in your strategy. So, how you want to fix this is up to your strategy.

For a quick fix, you can use:

`profit_target       = close * (1 + long_profit_percent)`

This will use the entry price for the trade in the TP calculation.